# TypeScript property lookup using filter function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I need to find an array of keys to pass to my UI component using the filter function. But TS warn always raises a type error.

I've tried

```
['is_in_building', 'has_outside_access'].filter((v: keyof Unit) => Boolean(unit[v]));
```

But it still doesn't work.

`is_in_building`, `has_outside_access` did exist in type Unit. And the first argument `v` of the filter function can't be something else.

type.ts

```
type Unit = {
  is_in_building: boolean,
  has_outside_access: boolean,
  other_keys: boolean,
}
```

App.tsx

```
<Checkbox.Group
    value={['is_in_building', 'has_outside_access'].filter(
        v => Boolean(unit[v]) //ts error
    )}
>
    <Checkbox value="is_in_building">In Building</Checkbox>
    <Checkbox value="has_outside_access">Outside Access</Checkbox>
</Checkbox.Group>
```

Error:(303, 20) TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'EnhancedUnit'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'EnhancedUnit'.

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgUwE4XALhgbwFAzzMAQwFsENokBLMAcwBpd9CayCBXYgI2QfxgkIAbQkgCeGMB25JsAXxgBeLIzxFSGAOQbeTFhgBMABh14BwsRgCMh43IDc2ANoa1CbRuZuAugDoAZpSCUMgAFABuigB8MABCICCCCIRgIYgo4I5hXgCU2Q5AA)

Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: What is enhanced unit?

Comment: it's the unit. I simplified some code

Answer (score 0):

Typescript infers the type of the array to be `string[]`, and type of `v` to be string. Type `Unit` does not have an index signature of type string to it, therefore indexed access with a string is considered to be unsafe.

To make it safe, you can explicitly specify the array to consist only of keys of Unit. Like so,

```
type Unit = {
  is_in_building: boolean,
  has_outside_access: boolean,
  other_keys: boolean,
}

const array: (keyof Unit)[] = ['is_in_building', 'has_outside_access']

<Checkbox.Group value={array.filter(v => Boolean(unit[v]))}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBQKlQEMBbCALikWHgEtUBzAGn0OMcqIFdSAjBK0LViAG2LwQVVLwHxcAX1wBjNDSiQkaKnC3oseYSXJUA5KaHtOVAEwAGSwURiJUqAEY7DxQG5cKtWAoCXhiNwAKAGsIEGQAM1gEFFQASgBtAF1MKDTTYwgLUw4CjP8QsIA6OLpRYARwgDdMAD4oACFkZFEIYlRwzWS0hoyUlL8gA)

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is that TypeScript can't recognize the array contains only keys of the type `Unit`.

So you can help TypeScript to know more about your code like this:

```
(["is_in_building", "has_outside_access"] as Array<keyof Unit>).filter((v) => Boolean(unit[v]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is throwing that error is due to the fact that the array you are filtering through are just strings and you can potentially access keys in `unit` that do not exist.

There are two solutions to this.

```
// 1. You know the keys you are filtering will Always be a keyof Unit
interface Unit {
  is_in_building: boolean;
  has_outside_access: boolean;
  other_keys: boolean;
}
const unit: Unit = {
  is_in_building: true,
  has_outside_access: false,
  other_keys: false
};

// What has changed : Assert that the array is actually a list of keys of Unit
const keysICareAbout: Array<keyof Unit> = ['is_in_building', 'has_outside_access'];
keysICareAbout.filter(v => unit[v]);
```

```
// 2. You might ask for keys that are not present in Unit
interface Unit {
  [s: string]: any; // What has changed : Unit can be checked against any key (even if it doesn't exist
  is_in_building: boolean;
  has_outside_access: boolean;
  other_keys: boolean;
}
const unit: Unit = {
  is_in_building: true,
  has_outside_access: false,
  other_keys: false
};

['is_in_building', 'has_outside_access'].filter(v => unit[v]);
```